# set text of input value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is probably a piece of cake for all, but im really not any good with javascript.

I would like to set the value of html input with javascript.

I have an input like this:

```
<input id="input-data" value=""/>
```

I would like to set the text of the value with javascript, meaning that if id pass value like "CocaCola" to input, it should display "CocaCola" in input

This is how i try

```
document.getElementById("input-data").value = "CocaCola";
```

But no data gets displayed in input. When i run debugger and put value as my watch, the "CocaCola" is stored in value.

What on earth am i missing?

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/ganL2vcc/. Are you running that code after the element is rendered to the page? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: @j08691 im not sure if i know the answer to your question because i'm not sure what that means. But yeh works for me in jsfiddle too

Comment: Press F12 to open the browser tools and look at the console tab, then reload your page and see if you get any messages.

Comment: there are no errors in console...when i debug code and set watch - document.getElementById("input-data).value ...there result is 'cocacola'... @j08691

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, the problem could be with the browser you are using...

Comment: same happens with chrome and firefox...must be something really stupid @MasterYoda

Comment: Please provide a sample code snippet showing exactly how you reference javascript in your code on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is under HTML tag, like this:

```
<input id="input-data" value=""/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("input-data").value = "CocaCola";
</script>
```

Or you can use:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("input-data").value = "CocaCola";
}
```

It works any time and anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Your JavaScript code to set value is right.

You can also try jQuery to set value like this,

```
 $('#input-data').value = 'CocaCola';
```

Comment: a) "it works" is never an answer. At best it's a comment, and several people have already commented about it. 2) the question doesn't even hint at jQuery, which is overkill for something this basic, not to mention that your jQuery is wrong.